# How to manipulate the product flavours of build.gradle through java code

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I want to modify the token and API urls from my java code so that I can create a development or release build depending on mode selected from my custom screen.
Below is the code used in build.gradle

```
 productFlavors {
    dev {
        buildConfigField "String", "TOKEN_URL", '"https://example.com"'
        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", '"https://api.ex"'
        versionCode getDevVersionCode()
    }
    prod {
        buildConfigField "String", "TOKEN_URL", '"https://release.example2.com"'
        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", '"https://api.release.ex"'
        versionCode getReleaseVersionCode()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first in app/build.gradle, add the `productFlavor` under android

```
productFlavors {
    qa {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_HTTP", "true"
    }
    staging {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_HTTP", "true"
    }
    live {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_HTTP", "false"
    }
}
```

then you need to create specific directories in app/src directory
[image]

finally, you just create a same name File in these different directories, like the following picture
[image]

in each ServerConstants(the name can be arbitrate)， you should reference specific variables of "TOKEN_URL" and "API_URL"

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my requirement is i have to switch between production and development when a user chooses a radio button.Using above structure it will automatically create builds as per variables mentioned in ServerConstants.java. Suppose I have created a live build but the user wants the api url to be set of development, this is the scenario required.

Comment: if so, it has nothing to do with build.gradle. you can just decalre two static constant variable. then refer it based on user's behavior

Comment: Seems to be the only solution . Thanks for the help